# Deploying Java Application to Heroku

Tags: java, maven, heroku, deployment, pom.xml

So I made a java web application with a normal pom.xml specifying my maven dependencies. Then, I went through the Heroku step by step tutorial on deploying their already-made web app, which did not help in the least bit. Then, I tried deploying the war, with no luck. Then I tried using the Maven plugin.  I'm not sure if Heroku or some blog has a step by step guide on deploying to Heroku, but I need one.  Can anyone go over what modifications need to be done to the pom.xml and what the procfile should be? And is it also necessary to have a main method in a java class? I thought each servlet was an entry point. My web app works fine on localhost and when I deploy the war on tomcat. It just doesn't work on Heroku no matter what I do to the pom.xml. I included my pom.xml.  [enter link description here](https://pastebin.com/Sv458jyu)

Comment: Have you looked at [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment#deployment-with-the-heroku-maven-plugin)?

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands:

```
$ heroku plugins:install heroku-cli-deploy
$ heroku deploy:war yourapp.war
```

Then read [WAR Deployment](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment) on Heroku's Dev Center.